# How to make a list that displays the top level subpages, and any subpages or siblings off of the current page

Tags: hierarchical

Lets say we are displaying a few family trees. We are currently on the family tree top-page,and we need our list to look like this:

*Family Trees*

- The Smiths
- The Joneses
- The Does

When the user clicks the Smiths, we want the list to look like this:

*The Smiths*

- The Smiths

  - Dave
  - Steve
  - Dolly
- The Joneses
- The Does

And when a user clicks on Steve, we want the list to also look like this:

*Dave Smith*

- The Smiths

  - Dave
  - Steve
  - Dolly
- The Joneses
- The Does

So, we need to display a list of all subpages and siblings of the current page, as well as all siblings of every step in the hierarchy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi *@Joseph Carrington*: What post type are these? Are they Pages, or custom post types?  Also, do you want to load all data when you load the page and use jQuery+CSS to expose the ones you want, or do you want to use jQuery+AJAX to load the subpages on demand? *(If you have **lots** of these the latter may be your only viable option.)*

Comment: Well, ideally I would be using PHP and as many built in WP functions as possible. I don't see the need to involve javascript at all.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I never saw your response. For future reference it's because you didn't @reply me so the site never notified me of your comment. Can you answer what the different menu items are; Pages or Custom Post Types, Categories, Tags, etc?

Answer (score 1):

What you write reminded me to some plugin / widget I know of. It's related to [Silo Web Design](http://www.semiologic.com/resources/seo/silo/) and the plugin is the [Silo Widgets Plugin For WordPress](http://www.semiologic.com/software/silo/). In SemPro you can make use of inline widgets to display something like that within posts.

Answer (score 0):

This was a pretty decent plugin for displaying a flexible list of pages last time i tried it(no need for it myself)..

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flexi-pages-widget/

If anything, you should be able to look to that plugin for some ideas and inspiration on how to tackle it..

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this once. You can do it without a plugin and without javascript. You might have to tweak it a little to work exactly as you need it but it should give you the right idea; displaying parent pages and their children etc.

Here is the tutorial I used: http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/02/creating-a-submenu-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Forget plugins, i had the same problem and plugins created a whole raft of mess and too many db calls.

This code will do the business for you - for ease of use, stick it in a content part and include it like so:

```
get_template_part( 'subnav', 'pagename' );
```

The problem is, you already know your children, and you know your parents. I tried using the wp-list-pages function , with echo set to false andincluding id's but that got a little messy. This solution isnt perfect but it's far cleaner than using a plugin or two.

In a nutshell - you want the absolute top parent id, then you want to get all the children of the current posts ancestors:

```
function get_top_id($id){
   $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post );
   return $parents[count($parents)-1]; 
}


function get_sub_pages($id){

    global $post;

    // get the ancestors for this depth
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post );

    //add the post id to the list in order to get the children
    array_unshift($parents, $post->ID);

    //reverse the order of the array
    $parents = array_reverse($parents);

    // specify to get all children of the top level parent
    $args = array( 'child_of' => $id); 

    if($subPages = get_pages($args)):

        // start at the first  $parents array key
       $curParent = 0;
       $childList = '<ul>';

       if($id == $post->ID) $class = ' class="selected"';
       $childList .= "<li" . $class ."><a href='". get_page_link( $id )."'>Introduction</a></li>" ;

       foreach( $subPages as $page ) :

            // only add the item if:
            // a: the pages parent is in the ancestors array

            if(in_array($page->post_parent, $parents)){ 

                // get the key of the page parent within the $parents array 
                // this helps us check if we are going to a deeper/higher level
                $pageParent = array_search($page->post_parent, $parents);

                if($curParent != $pageParent){

                    // if we are going deeper, add a new list for the children
                    if($pageParent > $curParent){
                        $childList .= '<ul>';
                    }

                    // if we are going higher, check how many depth changes                        
                    if($pageParent < $curParent){                            
                        $depthChange = $curParent - $pageParent;

                        // close off all the children of higher depths
                        while($depthChange > 0){
                            $childList .= '</li></ul>';
                            $depthChange --;
                        }                            
                    }

                    // set the new parent level
                    $curParent = $pageParent;                        
                }

                $class = '';
                if($page->ID == $post->ID) $class = ' class="selected"';
                if($page->ID == $post->post_parent) $class = ' class="parent"';

                // leave off the trailing <li> in case there are children to be added to this
                $childList .= "<li" . $class . "><a href='". get_page_link( $page->ID )."'>". $page->post_title . "</a>" ;

            }

       endforeach;

       $childList .= '</ul>';

    endif;

    return $childList;
}

// get the absolute top level parent of this page
$topID = get_top_id();

// if no parent, we are ar the top
if(!$topID) $topID = $post->ID;

echo get_sub_pages($topID);
```

This code also adds the class 'selected' to the current post, and 'parent' to the current post parent within the list.

Hope that helps someone!